# Converting std::string to upper case: major performance difference?

Tags: c++

So I was playing around with some code and wanted to see which method of converting a std::string to upper case was most efficient.  I figured that the two would be somewhat similar performance-wise, but I was terribly wrong.  Now I'd like to find out why.

The first method of converting the string works as follows: for each character in the string (save the length, iterate from 0 to length), if it's between 'a' and 'z', then shift it so that it's between 'A' and 'Z' instead.

The second method works as follows: for each character in the string (start from 0, keep going till we hit a null terminator), apply the build in toupper() function.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

inline std::string ToUpper_Reg(std::string str)
{
    for (int pos = 0, sz = str.length(); pos < sz; ++pos)
    {
        if (str[pos] >= 'a' && str[pos] <= 'z') { str[pos] += ('A' - 'a'); }
    }

    return str;
}

inline std::string ToUpper_Alt(std::string str)
{
    for (int pos = 0; str[pos] != '\0'; ++pos) { str[pos] = toupper(str[pos]); }

    return str;
}


int main()
{
    std::string test = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789~!@#$%^&*()_+=-`'{}[]\\|\";:<>,./?";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) { ToUpper_Reg(test); /* ToUpper_Alt(test); */ }

    return 0;
}
```

The first method `ToUpper_Reg` took about **169 seconds** per 100 million iterations.
The second method `Toupper_Alt` took about **379 seconds** per 100 million iterations.

What gives?

---

*Edit:* I changed the second method so that it iterates the string how the first one does (set the length aside, loop while less than length) and it's a bit faster, but still about twice as slow.

---

*Edit 2:* Thanks everybody for your submissions!  The data I'll be using it on is guaranteed to be ascii, so I think I'll be sticking with the first method for the time being.  I'll keep in mind that `toupper` is locale specific for when/if I need it.

Comment: toupper is slower than what you do in _Reg because it does more than you do in Reg?

Comment: Why don't you also add the standard C++ in-place transformation, `std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), (int(*)(int))std::toupper);`? (You need to `#include <cctype>`, `<string>` and `<algorithm>`.)

Comment: Wow, that's a mouthful.  Out of curiosity, what's with the `(int(*)(int))` part?

Comment: @GigaWatt It tells the compiler to use the version of toupper which takes an integer and returns an integer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) uses the current locale to do case conversions, which involves a function call and other abstractions. So naturally, it will be slower. But it will also work on non-ASCII text.

Answer (score 5):

`toupper()` does more than just shift characters in the range [a-z]. For one thing it's locale dependent and can handle more than just ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

`toupper()` takes the locale into account so it can handle (some) international characters and is much more complex than just handling the character range 'a'-'z'.

Answer (score 3):

Well, `ToUpper_Reg()` doesn't work. For example, it doesn't turn my name into all uppercase characters. That said, `ToUpper_Alt()` also doesn't work because it `toupper()` gets passed a negative value on some platforms, i.e. it creates undefined behavior (normally a crash) when using it with my name. This is easily fixed, though, by correctly calling it something like this:

```
toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(str[pos]))
```

That said, the two versions of the code are not equivalent: the version onot using `toupper()` isn't writing the characters all the time while the latter version is: once everything is converted to uppercase it always takes the same branch after a test and then does nothing. You might want to change `ToUpper_Alt()` to look like this and retest:

```
inline std::string ToUpper_Alt(std::string str)
{
    for (int pos = 0; str[pos] != '\0'; ++pos) { 
        if (islower(static_cast<unsigned char>(str[pos])) {
           str[pos] = toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(str[pos]));
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

I would guess the difference is the writing: `toupper()` trades the comparison for an array look-up. The locale is quickly accessed and all `toupper()` does is get the current pointer and access the location at a given offset. With data in the cache this is probably as fast as the branch.

Comment: Nice catch on the difference in the number of writes.

Comment: Is it expensive to construct a new locale for every call to `std::toupper`? Should users generally cache a locale object to pass in instead?

Comment: @caps: it is fairly expensive to create a new `std::locale` object. A copy requires accessing a synchronized reference count increment. Creating a new `std::locale` and changing a facet requires an additional synchronized reference count access per facet. Default constructing a `std::locale` needs synchronized access to the global `std::locale` plus the cost of a copy. So, yes, you should keep the `std::locale` objects around. Note that the version of `std::toupper()` not using a `std::locale` parameter doesn't create one: it accesses C's locale entity instead!

Answer (score 0):

The second on involves a function call. a function call is an expensive operation in an inner loop. toupper also uses locales to determine how the character should be changed.

The advances of the call is that it is standard and will work regardless of character encoding on the host machine

That said, I would highly recommend use the boost function:

```
 boost::algorithm::to_upper
```

It is a template so is more than likely to be inlined, however it does involve locales. I would still use it.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/to_upper.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because the second one calls a C standard library function, that on the one hand isn't inlined, so you got the overhead of a function call. But even more important, this function probably does a lot more than just two comparisons, two jumps and two integer additions. It performs additional checks on the character and takes the current locale into account and all that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

std::toupper uses the current locale and the reason why this is slower than the C function is that the current locale is shared and mutable from different threads, so it's necessary to lock the locale object when it's accessed to ensure it's not switched during the call. This happens once per call to toupper and introduces quite a large overhead (obtaining the lock might require a syscall depending on implementation). One workaround if you want to get the performance and respect the locale is to get the locale object first (creating a local copy) and then call the toupper facet on your copy, thus avoiding the need to lock for each toupper call. See the link below for an example.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/ctype/toupper/

Answer (score 0):

The question has already been answered, but as an aside, replacing the guts of your loop in the first method with:

```
std::string::value_type &c = str[pos];
if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') { c += ('A' - 'a'); }
```

makes it even faster.  Maybe my compiler just sucks.